# Elasticsearch - Setting up default analyzers on all fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I've an Index where the mappings will vary drastically. Consider for example, I'm indexing Wikipedia `infobox` data of every other article. The data in infobox is not structured, neither its uniform. So, the data can be of the form:-

```
Data1- {
    'title': 'Sachin',
    'Age': 41,
    'Occupation': Cricketer
}

Data2- {
    'title': 'India',
    'Population': '23456987654',
    'GDP': '23',
    'NationalAnthem': 'Jan Gan Man'
}
```

Since all the fields are different and I want to apply Completion field on the relevant field, hence I'm thinking of applying analyzers on all the fields.

How can I apply analyzers on every field by default while indexing?

Comment: On all `string` fields, I presume?

Comment: Yes. Only on string fields. All other fields such as `int`, `double` should be not_analyzed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `_default_` template for your index, so that whenever new fields are added to it, those `string` fields will take the mapping from the `_default_` template:

```
{
  "template": "infobox*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "analyzer": "my_completion_analyzer",
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or if your index is not a daily/weekly one, you can just create it once with the `_default_` mapping defined:

```
PUT /infobox
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "analyzer": "my_completion_analyzer",
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Som this worked for most of the cases, but when I tried indexing another document with `birthYear` key in it, it returned `mapper_parsing_exception, failed to parse [birthYear]`

Comment: So, upon checking it actually creates the mapping schema of the type of first document indexed. The moment I index another document with different keys/fields, it throws an error.

Comment: Why exactly is this happening?

Comment: I wanted a type of mapping which was very generic/dynamic in nature.

Comment: `mapper_parsing_exception, failed to parse [birthYear]`

Comment: Okay. So I've identified the problem. The mapping that is getting generated for `birthYear` is of type `date`. And the data that I'm passing into `birthYear` is an empty string. Is there any way I can handle this?

Comment: That's a separate question, imo, and should be handled in a separate post.

Comment: Can you please have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185131/default-value-of-elasticsearch-date-field