# Default value of Elasticsearch Date Field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a dynamic mapping in ES using:

```
{
  "template": "infobox*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "analyzer": "my_completion_analyzer",
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, whenever I index a document having `date` field (`birthYear`), it automatically creates a field (`birthYear`) with `date` type. So, whenever I don't have a `birthYear`, I send an empty string `''`, which then raises an exception `mapper_parsing_exception, failed to parse [birthYear]`.

Is there any way I can handle this? Can I assign a default value?

Comment: Is `birthYear` of type date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either add `ignore_malformed: true` to all `date` fields or you set this globally:

**only `date` fields**:

```
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "string_fields": {
        "match": "*",
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "whitespace",
          "fielddata": {
            "format": "disabled"
          },
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "date_fields": {
        "match": "*",
        "match_mapping_type": "date",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "date",
          "ignore_malformed": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

**globally set**:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "analyzer": "whitespace",
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```